# Construct a specific length-doubling pseudorandom generator from a length-doubling pseudorandom

Tags: encryption, random-number-generator, pseudo-random-generator

Let $G$ be a length-doubling pseudorandom generator (i.e., for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and for
any $s\in\{0, 1\}^n$ it holds that $G(s)\in\{0, 1\}^{2n}$). Can you construct a length-doubling pseudorandom
generator $H$ such that $H(0^n)= 0^{2n}$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Hints: (1) What's the simplest construction you could make out of $G$ that would satisfy the additional $H(0^n) = 0^{2n} $ condition? (2) Can you prove that if $G$ is a pseudorandom generator, that construction of $H$ must be one as well? The heart of the problem seems to be to demonstrate that you know how to write such a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\forall s\in \{0,1\}^{n} \ : H(s)=G(s)\oplus G(0^n)\implies H(0^n)=G(0^n)\oplus G(0^n)=0^{2n}$

now, we'll prove by contradiction that $H$ is indeed a pseudo-random generator.

assuming that it's not we get that there exist an adversary D (PPT algo) such that for every polynomial p(n):

$|Pr_{s\leftarrow\{0,1\}^n}[D(H(s))=1]-Pr_{r\leftarrow\{0,1\}^n}[D(r)=1]|>1/p(n)$

Now, define the adversary $D'(v):=v\oplus G(0^n)$ for the PRG "$G$", and we're almost done:
$|Pr_{s\leftarrow\{0,1\}^n}[D'(G(s))=1]-Pr_{r\leftarrow\{0,1\}^n}[D'(r)=1]|=$
$|Pr_{s\leftarrow\{0,1\}^n}[D(G(s)\oplus G(0^n))=1]-Pr_{r\leftarrow\{0,1\}^n}[D((r)\oplus G(0^n)=1]|=$
$|Pr_{s\leftarrow\{0,1\}^n}[D(H(s))=1]-Pr_{r\leftarrow\{0,1\}^n}[D(r)=1]|>1/p(n)$

$\blacksquare$

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. As our current policy, we provide hints to homework questions and that is usually given in the comments.

Comment: @kelalaka that's **my post** though, and I've found the answer, thought I might as well post it to the use of someone in the future, if you can improve my answer you're welcome to do so.

Comment: In case anyone else reads this and has trouble figuring out the last equality: XORing a given number (in this case G(0^n)) with the group of all numbers {0,1}^2n results in the same group